# C++ union member object cannot be assigned to post-construction

Tags: c++, c++17

The test code (compiled -std=c++17) below is very simple. In it, assignment to any member of the union after the constructor has run appears to do nothing at all. I instantiate a `Union` that contains `Parent` and `Child` class members and then assign to the child member. I have tried several `Union` constructors (numbered 1-4). I print the raw memory after each step, but it never changes.

1. The raw memory doesn't change after assigning `u.child = assign_child;`. With constructor #3, the member should be initialized as `Parent` class, so presumably this should be overwritten with the child class and be different.
2. When using the empty constructor #1, calling `Print()` via pointer access with `u.Ptr()->Print()`  segfaults, but it works fine when called directly via member access. Why is that? I imagine this means either that G++ encodes the object type in the bytes at that location or the compiler is choosing a different code path depending on which constructor was used.
3. If I initialize the parent or child members in the `Union` constructor, `ptr->Print()` uses that type. That must mean either a) the compiler tracks which constructor was used and then calls the matching type later based on code analysis or b) the object type is encoded in the bytes at that location. Which is true?

```
#include <iostream> 
 
using namespace std; 
 
class Parent { 
public: 
    virtual void Print() {  
        cout << "Parent "; 
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Parent); i++) 
           printf("%x", ((char*)this)[i]); 
        cout << endl; 
    } 
}; 
 
class Child : public Parent { 
public: public:
    void Print() override {
        cout << "Child  ";
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Child); i++)
           printf("%x", ((char*)this)[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }
};

struct Union {
    union {
        Parent parent;
        Child child;
    };
    //Union(){ } // (1) crash on Ptr()->Print()
    //Union(){ p = Parent(); } // (2) crash on Ptr()->Print()
    Union(){ new (&parent) Parent(); } // (3) works
    //Union(){ new (&child) Child(); } // (4) works
    ~Union(){ }
    Child* Ptr() { return & child; }
};


int main() {
    Union u;
    cout << "original memory: parent/child.Print()" << endl;
    u.parent.Print(); // Parent ffffff88ffffff9d292cffffff845500 the values never change
    u.child.Print();  // Child  ffffff88ffffff9d292cffffff845500 the values never change

    cout << "\nmemory after assignment: parent/child.Print()" << endl;
    Child assign_child;
    u.child = assign_child;
    u.parent.Print();
    u.child.Print();

    cout << "\nmemory via pointer access as Child:" << endl;
    Child* child = u.Ptr();
    child->Print(); // crash with constructors 1 or 2

    cout << "\nmemory via pointer access as Parent:" << endl;
    Parent* parent = (Parent*) u.Ptr();
    parent->Print(); // crash with constructors 1 or 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::variant`.  With `union`  you have to manually manage the contained objects lifetime manually with placement new etc see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Union(){ new (&parent) Parent(); }
> ```

Your constructor activates the `parent` member.

> ```
> u.child.Print();
> ```

You access inactive member of the union. The behaviour of the program is undefined. Regardless of which constructor alternative you use, you access an inactive member at some point of the example.

To answer all of your questions: Behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

A well defined way to change the active member is to first destroy the previously active member:

```
parent.~Parent();
new (&child) Child();
```

Storing a separate instance of the parent class in a union with derived seems like a strange design.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If I use the 1st constructor (no initialization) and then assign `child` later via `u.child = assign_child;`, u.Ptr()->Print() doesn't work. I don't understand, because the member was just assigned. Why is assignment via placement new different from equals? This issue presents itself even if I remove all references and access to `parent`.

Comment: @evo8198 If you assign a non-trivial member of union that is inactive, the behaviour of the program is undefined. Only way to activate a non-trivial member of union is to use placement new. `Why is assignment via placement new different from equals?` Assignment doesn't invoke constructors. It is an operation that is performed on a pre-existing object. When there is no pre-existing object, there is a contradiction. Assignment of a trivial union member is special in that it starts the lifetime of the inactive member. That special case does not apply to non-trivial members.

Comment: Okay thanks, I believe that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an explanation what exactly happens, but what you are trying is not covered by the C++ standard (it is undefined behavior).

In principle you are only allowed to use (-> read/assign) the union member that was constructed. With unions you have to manually construct and destruct members if you want to make another member active.

In your example you construct the `parent` member (and not `child`) and hence you are only allowed to access `parent` (i.e. access of `&child` in `ptr()` and calling functions of Child for instance is disallowed)

There is an exception to this rule: It is allowed to read from an inactive union member if that is part of a common initial sequence with the currently active member.

If your classes `Parent`and `Child` were standard layout types it would be possible to construct the `child` union member and then read from `parent` union member.

But not the other way round (as you try to do) and only (!) if you have standard layout types (which you dont have due to `virtual`)